# How to recursively decode a word given an integer?

Tags: c, recursion, encoding, decoding

Each letter is assigned a number corresponding to its position in the alphabet. 'a' is 0, 'b' is 1, 'c' is 2, etc.

All letters are lower case

A one-letter word's encoding is its number.

If the encoding for the first n-1 letters of a word is x, and the encoding for the nth letter is m, then the encoding of the n-letter word is x*26+m.

I understand that the logic is this:

If the word contains only a single letter, the encoding is between 0 and 25.

If the word contains two letters, then take the firstletter*26+secondletter

If the word contains three letters, then (firstletter*26+secondletter)*26+thirdletter

and so on until you have encoded the whole thing.

I am not sure how to proceed past the base case. Please help!

This is what I have so far:

```
char print_letter(unsigned int number)
{
    char c = number + 97;
    if (number <= 25)
    {
        printf("%c\n", c);
        return(c);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: print_letter: Received "
            "input %d,", number);
        fprintf(stderr, " between 0 and 25 expected.");
        return('-');
    }
}

void print_word(unsigned int number)
{
    if(number <= 25)
        print_letter(number);
    else
    {
        print_letter((number / 26) % 26);
        print_word(number / 26);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as text, rather than as an image.

Comment: @kevin Sorry about that. This is my first time using stackoverflow. I added it as text

Answer (score 0):

You have the formula

```
number = x*26+m
```

Now you have number and want to calculate x and m. How to go about that?

```
m = number % 26
x = (number - m) / 26
```

So your code must look like this:

```
void print_word(unsigned int number)
{
    if(number <= 25)
        print_letter(number);
    else
    {
        int m = number % 26;
        int x = (number - m) / 26;

        print_word(x);
        print_letter(m);
    }
}
```

Note that you must call print_word before print_letter to have the correct order of the letters in the output.